# Mathematica/CUDA reduce execution time

Tags: c++, c, cuda, wolfram-mathematica, montecarlo

I'm writing a simple monte carlo simulation for particle transport. My approach is writing a kernel for CUDA and execute it as a Mathematica function.

Kernel:

```
#include "curand_kernel.h"
#include "math.h"

extern "C" __global__ void monteCarlo(Real_t *transmission, mint seed, mint pathN) {
curandState rngState;

int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

curand_init(seed, index, 0, &rngState);

if (index < pathN) {
    //-------------start one packet run----------------------

    float packetWeight = 1.0;
    int m = 0;

    while(packetWeight > 0.0){

        //MONTE CARLO CODE

        // Test: still in the sample?
            if(z_coordinate > sampleThickness){
                packetWeight = 0;
                z_coordinate = sampleThickness;
                transmission[index]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    //-------------end one packet run------------------------
}
}
```

Mathematica code:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"];
cudaBM = CUDAFunctionLoad[code, 
"monteCarlo", {{_Real, "Output"}, _Integer, _Integer}, 256, 
"UnmangleCode" -> False];


pathN = 100000;
result = 0;  (*count for transmitted particles*)
For[j = 0, j < 10, j++,
   buffer = CUDAMemoryAllocate["Float", 100000];
   cudaBM[buffer, 1490, pathN];
   resultOneRun = Total[CUDAMemoryGet[buffer]];
   result = result + resultOneRun;
];
```

Everything seems to work so far, but the speed improvement compared to the pure C code without CUDA is neglible. I have two problems:

1. the curand_init() function is executed by all threads at the beginning of every sumulation step -> can I call this function once for all threads?
2. the kernel returns to Mathematica a very large array of reals (100 000). I know, that the bottleneck of CUDA is the channel bandwidth between GPU and CPU. I need only the sum of all elements of the list, so it would be more efficient to calculate the sum of the list elements in the GPU and send only one real number to the CPU.

Comment: Can't you use `CUDATotal` ?

Comment: `CUDATotal` will be executed after the result array is copied back to the CPU memory. I want to avoid copying the whole result array to the CPU memory. I think the solution must be in the C part of the code. Thank you for your response.

Comment: If so I totally misunderstood the documentation on this; thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you need to execute curand_init() once for all threads, can you just do that in the CPU and pass that as an argument to CUDA?

2) How about a "**device** float sumTotal" function which sums and returns your values? Have you copied as much *transmission data into a shared memory buffer?

Answer (score 0):

As per CURAND docs, 
"Calls to curand_init() are slower than calls to curand() or curand_uniform(). Large offsets to curand_init() take more time than smaller offsets. It is much faster to save and restore random generator state than to recalculate the starting state repeatedly."

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html#topic_1_3_4

Also please look into this thread for more details
[CUDA program causes nvidia driver to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182151/cuda-program-causes-nvidia-driver-to-crash)